# Evaluating a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am currently trying to integrate the stochastic integral $\int_0^te^{\theta s}dW(s)$. My approach is to basically apply ito's lemma. If $ F(X(t), t) =e^{\theta t} X(t)$ where $dX(t)=dW(t)\,\,with\,\,\mu=0,\,\,\sigma=1$,

Then
$$
dF(X(t),t)=\theta e^{\theta t} X(t)\,dt \,+\,e^{\theta t}\,dW(t)
$$

And we can then integrate both the LHS and the RHS, my result was
$$
e^{\theta t} X(t)=\int_0^t \theta e^{\theta s} X(s)\,ds \,+\,\int_0^t e^{\theta s}\,dW(s)
$$

However if we rearrange them

$$
\int_0^t e^{\theta s}\,dW(s)=e^{\theta t}X(t)\,-\,\theta\int_0^t e^{\theta s} X(s)\,ds
$$

In this case, the RHS seem to cancel out and equate to zero, I am just curious at which step did I go wrong?

Comment: Unless $\theta=0$ and the integral is trivially equal to $W(t)$ you won't find a function $F(W(t),t)$ that represents that integral. Hint: does the integral depend only on $W(t)$ and $t$ or on more than that ? Hint: path of $W$. The formulas you got are just the integration by parts formula which allow to express the $dW$ integral as a $ds$ integral. There is a factor $\theta$ missing in front of $\int_0^te^{\theta s}X(s)\,ds$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for pointing the missing factor out! I have made the adjustments. I would like to first clarify if my representation of $dW$ as a $ds$ integral is even correct?

On the other question on what the integral depends on, pardon me if I give nonsensical answers as I am only just learning about stochastic integrals. Does the integral depend also on the value of $W(t)$ at each infinitesimal timestep? i.e. $t=1,2,...,t$?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes. Please familiarize yourself with the integration-by-parts formula which you can find in every source that teaches stochastic integrals.